# K8 ingress not working on Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I am trying to get a simple nginx server running using minikube with external access. For some reason, the Ingress isn't working and I can't work out why.

Here is the **YAML file for the nginx pod**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    name: my-nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Next, **the YAML for a service**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    name: my-nginx
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: my-nginx
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

...and finally, **the YAML for an Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

At this point that I can run:
`kubectl get ingress`
and see:

```
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
nginx-ingress   nginx   *       192.168.49.2   80      141m
```

And so when I run `curl http://192.168.49.2/` I would expect to receive the default nginx webpage. Instead, curl just hangs.

Now, I know that the nginx server is running on the pod, because I can see it's response when I run `kubectl exec -it nginx-pod -- curl localhost`. But for some reason the Ingress isn't working.

Running `kubectl describe ingress nginx-ingress` returns:

```
Name:             nginx-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.49.2
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /   nginx-service:8080 (10.244.0.16:80)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                  ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    5m49s (x2 over 6m2s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

...which looks OK to me.

Can anyone spot the problem?

---

EDIT: Further experimentation shows that these kubernetes files work as expected when run on an Ubuntu box.
I originally tested this on a Windows box using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu) on which it doesn't work.
That sort of solves the problem....

Answer (score 0):

add the below in Service yml

```
  selector:
    name: my-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and restarted the service. Didn't work.